# Increment Object set javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object set

```
var obj = {
 ref01:{
 test:"abc"
},
ref02:{
 test:"xyz"
},
ref03:{
 test:"pqr"
}
}
```

and I have new object

```
const test = {
  test:"def"
}
```

I want to update the object above with increment value of **ref**
Now ref is03 , I want to append like  ref04 and increment each time based on existing obj.

```
var obj = {
 ref01:{
 test:"abc"
},
ref02:{
 test:"xyz"
},
ref03:{
 test:"pqr"
},
ref04:{
 test:"def"
}
}
```

i tried object.assign but its directly passing the value .
`obj = object.assign(obj,{ref:test})`

So how can i get it ?

Comment: It is bad practice to have properties with a sequential number as suffix. Don't do this. Arrays were invented for this purpose.

Comment: Why you don't simply store your data in an array?  `obj = [{ref: 'abc'}, {ref: 'def'}]` So you can use `obj.push({ref: 'ghi'})`

Comment: @trincot just out of curiosity: why is it bad practice?

Comment: its s response from Api @trincot

Comment: i want the ref as increment since comes from Api , i need to add new ref incremented and send it back @Yukulélé

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a list: i.e.

```
const obj = {
    testObjects: [
        {
            test: 'abc'
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

then you can just run:

```
obj.testObjects.push({test: 'xyz'});
```

OR if this is an API response you can't change the schema of:

```
//find last index so you can add the ref obj
const getFormattedIndex = (idx) => String(idx).padStart(2, '0');
let i = 1;
while(obj[`ref${getFormattedIndex(i)}`]) {
   i++;
}
//add object with the correct sequential key
obj[`ref${getFormattedIndex(i)}`] = {test: 'xyz'};
```

or you could be a bad person and use scope-bleed with a ghetto for loop :

```
//find last index so you can add the ref obj
const getFormattedIndex = (idx) => String(idx).padStart(2, '0');
for (var i = 1; obj[`ref${getFormattedIndex(i)}`]; i++);
//add object with the correct sequential key
obj[`ref${getFormattedIndex(i)}`] = {test: 'xyz'};
```

Comment: How does this run ? @bturner1273

Comment: here I'll edit because I see it is an api response now that I assume you can't change

Comment: Yes, i need to append into existing object set with new ref increment.